# Is one allowed to shorten prayers if he is travelling for more than four days but not staying in one place for more than that?

Tags: fiqh, travelling, salat-al-qasr

If one embarks on a journey in which he will stay in different cities, each city being more than 120 miles apart and are more than 200 miles away from his home town, is he allowed to shorten prayers considering that he may stay at each city for less than four days but his travel will extend to more than four days?

Comment: Yes, what makes you think differently? It would only make a difference if intended to stay at one location more than four days (20 consecutive prayers) than there he should pray as if he were a resident, if he didn't intend and it happend that's a different story!

Comment: @Medi1Saif there seems to be a difference of opinion as to for how long  can traveller shorten his prayers, Shafi's say 4 days while Hanafis say 15, while in reality there this is not explicilty defined by the prophet or in the Quran, but lets say one is to take the safe approach and consider to be 4 days only because the majority of scholars agree to this then does the four day period restart every time he arrives in a new city?

Comment: I have a feeling I am over complicating this, I am not convinced that this concession has got a time limt

Comment: yes as explained in my edited comment. The ibadis and ibn Tayymiyyah say as long as he left home he is on a journey, but with a slight difference in opinion and definition.

Comment: @Medi1Saif makes sense this is what I thought as well. What if one of those cities is his parent's were he used to live, is he still a traveller?

Comment: Home means his usual residence AFAIK.

Comment: @Medi1Saif that's also what I thought but I got confused when scholars used the term 'Home Town' whith out defining it. How about if there is no hardship for one to preform prayers in full (I think this goes against the sunnah considering there is no narration of the prophet stating that he prayed in full while travelling?